# Reading data for a byte array from a file

Tags: c++, arrays, byte

I am working on a function right now that has 3 parameters. One of the parameters is the length of the input array in bytes. It's an int, so if length = 4, then it's saying the length of the input array is 4 bytes (the input and the output array are the other 2 parameters). If length is not a multiple of 4, we need to pad it with zeros until it is. My TA told me I should read the length in from the file and store it in a byte array, and then told me I should pad it with 0x00 until it is a multiple of four. That leads me to my questions:

1) how do I declare a byte array?
2) is padding it with zeros as easy as including [..., 0x00, 0x00, 0x00] as elements in the array?

Comment: No he didn't. He told you to read in the length, round it up to a multiple of 4, create a byte array of that length, read in the data, and pad the byte array with zeros if necessary,

Comment: Yes exactly. I'm glad you had the ability to clarify my poor rephrasing of the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do I declare a byte array?

uint8_t array[size];

> padding an array

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < padding_size; ++i)
{
  array[i] = 0;
}
```

Another technique is to set the array to the pad values, then replace the necessary slots with values:

```
std::fill(&array[0], &array[size], 0);
array[3] = value;
```

If you are performance bound, you may want to unroll the loop and perform multiple assignments:

```
array[0] = 0;
array[1] = 0x0; // Same as 0.
array[2] = 0;
array[3] = value;
```

Most computers prefer to process data instructions.  Jump or branching tends to irritate them, because they need to spend time evaluating the branch or jump.